# Android studio does not recognise (compile) changes anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've a few symptoms currently, starting today without any updates of android studio prior:

- If I change xml files and add layouts with new ids, the IDE does find this ids, the `Binding` class does find but if I want to run my app I get the `error: cannot find symbol` error for my `mBinding.layout` call in code.
- I have an xml file that contains my changelog, if I change this file and compile again, those changes are not compiled into my apk.

**What I tried and checked**

- to solve the first issue I made sure, that no flavour or similar is excluding the file I change => the xml file I change is in the default resoure folder and is included in each flavour
- I made sure no gradle task or similar is changing any resources (I don't use such things in this project)
- I made a clean build, called invalide/restart android studios cache, manually refreshed all gradle projects and finally, deleted the complete output folder where my project does save temporary/intermediate/... files all without success

After all this steps, if I rebuild my app (possible if I change my changelog xml) I still don't see this change in my apk. And if I add a view to a layout, the `Binding` finds it but again, if I want to build the project, the `error: cannot find symbol` comes again for the `mBinding.layout` code line...

Any ideas where I could look next?